# RAR archives with java

Tags: java, archive, rar

Is there a good java API for manipulating RAR archive files someone could recommend? Googling did not turn up anything overwhelmingly convincing.

Comment: Manipulating, no, because RAR is a closed format. You are allowed to unrar stuff as a developer, but that's about it. Note: I am not a lawyer, but just somebody that went the same path and walked into this one myself.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could try [JUnRar](https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar), "a RAR handling API implemented in pure Java" (quoting the site).

Answer (score 4):

There is also this fork from SF(@Fabian's answer and this one are forked from an old SF project):

https://github.com/jukka/java-unrar

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you.

[raroscope](http://code.google.com/p/raroscope/)

A pure Java library for scanning and enumerating RAR archive contents

Comment: As of 2017 it cannot yet unrar, but it was the only updated this year

Comment: As of 2019 it cannot unrar. The reason may be because of the license of rar files