# How can I extract all multi-part ZIP/RAR archives in a directory?

Tags: java, compression, zip

I need to extract all the multi-part ZIP and RAR archives in a given path? Does Java have any inbuilt methods for doing this? If not, would someone happen to know of a free library that does this?

Thanks.

Comment: You could install unzip and unrar and just invoke those. It's the easiest way assuming this is feasible in your particular scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Loop all files in the directory - [`new File(dir).listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29), possibly using a `FilenameFilter` to retain only those whose extension is .zip
2. You can use the `java.util.zip` package, or commons-compress. But my experience shows that using the ant [Zip task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) programatically is way easier. (You'd need the ant jar on the classpath). This is for .zip files. For RAR you'd need another utility. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561107/rar-archives-with-java). The URL in the answer does not open, but the name of the project is valid - google it.

Comment: I found a copy using Google Code. I don't know if it is the original or if it's been modified. Does JUnrar handle multi-part/spanned archives?