# How to compress text file to rar format using java program

Tags: java

Is there any java library by which we can compress a plain text file(.txt) into winRAR format(.rar). I have been searching in google but couldn't find any relevant library which does that.

Comment: Seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561107/rar-archives-with-java

Comment: take a look here http://www.catacombae.org/jlrarx.html#rarlib and then   here http://www.unrarlib.org/ wrapping a jni layer on this should be no problem.

Answer (score 7):

you can always do

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rar -a somefile.txt");
```

Comment: This looks good. But do we have control on the process once it gets rared? Bcoz i want to copy that RAR to some other location

Comment: create a temp directory, rar the files to that directory, copy the context of the temp directory to where you want, and then delete the temp directory,  you can do that with a bach script and have Runtime.getRuntime().exec call the script

Answer (score 3):

I think RAR is not open-source format. I'd rather use ZIP - it's built-in in Java.

Comment: i tried to zip 7 GB file but it says the zip cannot be done for files larger than 4 GB file size.

Answer (score 2):

RAR is a proprietary format, and I don't know of any library to create it (although there seem to be some that can read it). Any reason why you wouldn't use another, more open format like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) (for compression), or plain [Zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) (for universal compatibility)?

Comment: +1 RAR is both proprietary and closed. I've always wondered why it has such traction in the geek culture.

Comment: I didn't try 7zip but for Zip the limitation is only 4 GB. we cannot zip more than 4 GB file.

Comment: 4Gb limit was long in Java, but apparently [no more](http://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/zip64_support_for_4g_zipfile) (I didn't test it myself, though). 7z supports [files with sizes up to 16000000000 GB](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html).

Answer (score 1):

(From the question, of which this one is a duplicate - [RAR archives with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561107/rar-archives-with-java))

You could try JUnRar, "a RAR handling API implemented in pure Java" (quoting the site).

Comment: that only reads rar, most (if not all) open source tools cannot write the rar format.

Comment: probably - that's why I don't claim it as my own answer

Answer (score 1):

No you can not do it. Only *WinRAR* can create rar file. There is only a [unrar](http://www.unrarlib.org/) library for it.

Answer (score 1):

One reason to use RAR: It is sooooo much better than ZIP. For example: One of our production print files has a lot of repetition (including images) in it. 142 MB large, it zips to about 80MB. RAR seems to detect these repetitions and the resulting file is not even 2MB!

Answer (score 0):

Why RAR? as others have mentioned, RAR is not open.

Java has native ZIP API.
[Java Zip API: How to Create a Zip File Using Java](https://web.archive.org/web/20121028102015/http://rakasuniverse.info/2010/07/11/java-zip-api-how-to-create-a-zip-file-using-java/)

Comment: the page that you specified is not available :(