# Using java to extract .rar files

Tags: java, extract, rar

I am looking a ways to unzip `.rar` files using Java and where ever I search i keep ending up with the same tool - `JavaUnRar`. I have been looking into unzipping `.rar` files with this but all the ways i seem to find to do this are very long and awkward like in [this example](https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar/blob/6f32323c983015d96c64084418793853f514b519/testutil/src/main/java/de/innosystec/unrar/testutil/ExtractArchive.java)

I am currently able to extract `.tar`, `.tar.gz`, `.zip` and `.jar` files in 20 lines of code or less so there must be a simpler way to extract `.rar` files, does anybody know?

Just if it helps anybody this is the code that I am using to extract both `.zip` and `.jar` files, it works for both

```
 public void getZipFiles(String zipFile, String destFolder) throws IOException {
    BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
                                       new BufferedInputStream(
                                             new FileInputStream(zipFile)));
    ZipEntry entry;
    while (( entry = zis.getNextEntry() ) != null) {
        System.out.println( "Extracting: " + entry.getName() );
        int count;
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            new File( destFolder + "/" + entry.getName() ).mkdirs();
            continue;
        } else {
            int di = entry.getName().lastIndexOf( '/' );
            if (di != -1) {
                new File( destFolder + "/" + entry.getName()
                                             .substring( 0, di ) ).mkdirs();
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( destFolder + "/"
                                                     + entry.getName() );
        dest = new BufferedOutputStream( fos );
        while (( count = zis.read( data ) ) != -1) 
            dest.write( data, 0, count );
        dest.flush();
        dest.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: By the variety of zipping files I assume you are in linux env. Why don't you call shell commands from Java. It will be sorter and faster.

Comment: No i am actually using windows but the application i am working on at the moment has specifications to be able to unzip .tar.gz files so I have to do it... I want it to be a stand alone application so I don't really want to be doing calls outside of the application if i can help it

Answer (score 21):

You are able to extract `.gz`, `.zip`, `.jar` files as they use number of compression algorithms built into the Java SDK.

The case with **RAR** format is a bit different. RAR is a **proprietary** archive file format. [RAR license](http://www.buyrar.com/Prices.asp?Type=License) does not allow to include it into software development tools like Java SDK.

The best way to *unrar* your files will be using 3rd party libraries such as [junrar](https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar).

You can find some references to other Java RAR libraries in SO question [RAR archives with java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/561107/1916110). Also SO question [How to compress text file to rar format using java program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8804329/1916110) explains more on different workarounds (e.g. using `Runtime`).

Comment: I just set up junrar and it worked great in a mac. It requires Apache Commons, Apache Commons VFS and log4j.

Comment: But if it's a proprietary format, how is VFS working with it? I haven't found a `Runtime` methods in its code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/index.html

In addition to supporting a large number of archive formats, version 16.02-2.01 has full support for RAR5 extraction with:

- password protected archives
- archives with encrypted headers
- archives splitted in volumes

gradle

```
implementation 'net.sf.sevenzipjbinding:sevenzipjbinding:16.02-2.01'
implementation 'net.sf.sevenzipjbinding:sevenzipjbinding-all-platforms:16.02-2.01'
```

or maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
    <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding</artifactId>
    <version>16.02-2.01</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
    <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding-all-platforms</artifactId>
    <version>16.02-2.01</version>
</dependency>
```

And code example

```java
import net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.ExtractOperationResult;
import net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.IInArchive;
import net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.SevenZip;
import net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.impl.RandomAccessFileInStream;
import net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.simple.ISimpleInArchiveItem;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Responsible for unpacking archives with the RAR extension.
 * Support Rar4, Rar4 with password, Rar5, Rar5 with password.
 * Determines the type of archive itself.
 */
public class RarExtractor {

    /**
     * Extracts files from archive. Archive can be encrypted with password
     *
     * @param filePath path to .rar file
     * @param password string password for archive
     * @return map of extracted file with file name
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Map<InputStream, String> extract(String filePath, String password) throws IOException {
        Map<InputStream, String> extractedMap = new HashMap<>();

        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
        RandomAccessFileInStream randomAccessFileStream = new RandomAccessFileInStream(randomAccessFile);
        IInArchive inArchive = SevenZip.openInArchive(null, randomAccessFileStream);

        for (ISimpleInArchiveItem item : inArchive.getSimpleInterface().getArchiveItems()) {
            if (!item.isFolder()) {
                ExtractOperationResult result = item.extractSlow(data -> {
                    extractedMap.put(new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)), item.getPath());

                    return data.length;
                }, password);

                if (result != ExtractOperationResult.OK) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            String.format("Error extracting archive. Extracting error: %s", result));
                }
            }
        }

        return extractedMap;
    }
}
```

P.S.
@BorisBrodski https://github.com/borisbrodski Happy 40th birthday to you! Hope you had a great celebration. Thanks for your work!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library `junrar`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.junrar</groupId>
   <artifactId>junrar</artifactId>
   <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Code example:

```java
File f = new File(filename);
Archive archive = new Archive(f);
archive.getMainHeader().print();
FileHeader fh = archive.nextFileHeader();
while(fh!=null){        
    File fileEntry = new File(fh.getFileNameString().trim());
    System.out.println(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileEntry);
    archive.extractFile(fh, os);
    os.close();
    fh=archive.nextFileHeader();
}
```

Comment: Beware, junrar does not support RAR v5

Answer (score 1):

you could simply add this maven dependency to you code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.junrar</groupId>
    <artifactId>junrar</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

and then use this code for extract rar file:

```
        File rar = new File("path_to_rar_file.rar");
    File tmpDir = File.createTempFile("bip.",".unrar");
    if(!(tmpDir.delete())){
        throw new IOException("Could not delete temp file: " + tmpDir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    if(!(tmpDir.mkdir())){
        throw new IOException("Could not create temp directory: " + tmpDir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    System.out.println("tmpDir="+tmpDir.getAbsolutePath());
    ExtractArchive extractArchive = new ExtractArchive();
    extractArchive.extractArchive(rar, tmpDir);
    System.out.println("finished.");
```

Answer (score 0):

This method helps to extract files to streams from rar(RAR5) file stream if you have input stream. In my case I was processing MimeBodyPart from email.

The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65339381/2266229) from @Alexey Bril didn't work for me.

Dependencies are the same

Gradle

```
implementation 'net.sf.sevenzipjbinding:sevenzipjbinding:16.02-2.01'
implementation 'net.sf.sevenzipjbinding:sevenzipjbinding-all-platforms:16.02-2.01'
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
    <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding</artifactId>
    <version>16.02-2.01</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
    <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding-all-platforms</artifactId>
    <version>16.02-2.01</version>
</dependency>
```

Code

```
private List<InputStream> getInputStreamsFromRar5InputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    List<InputStream> inputStreams = new ArrayList<>();
    
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("tempRarArchive-", ".rar", null);

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        fos.write(is.readAllBytes());
        fos.flush();
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(tempFile, "r")) {// open for reading
            try (IInArchive inArchive = SevenZip.openInArchive(null, // autodetect archive type
                    new RandomAccessFileInStream(raf))) {
                // Getting simple interface of the archive inArchive
                ISimpleInArchive simpleInArchive = inArchive.getSimpleInterface();

                for (ISimpleInArchiveItem item : simpleInArchive.getArchiveItems()) {
                    if (!item.isFolder()) {
                        ExtractOperationResult result;
                        final InputStream[] IS = new InputStream[1];

                        final Integer[] sizeArray = new Integer[1];
                        result = item.extractSlow(new ISequentialOutStream() {
                            /**
                             * @param bytes of extracted data
                             * @return size of extracted data
                             */
                            @Override
                            public int write(byte[] bytes) {
                                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
                                sizeArray[0] = bytes.length;
                                IS[0] = new BufferedInputStream(is); // Data to write to file
                                return sizeArray[0];
                            }
                        });

                        if (result == ExtractOperationResult.OK) {
                            inputStreams.add(IS[0]);
                        } else {
                            log.error("Error extracting item: " + result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    } finally {
        tempFile.delete();
    }

    return inputStreams;

}
```