# Decompress Rar file in Android

Tags: android, rar, compression

I want to learn how to decompress a .rar file in android. Zip files can be easily decompressed using ZipStream. Is there any similar way for rar files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized this with jUnrar from here
https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar

Create a new package within your Android src directory called 
com.github.junrar
You should delete com.github.junrar.vfs2 because it has some dependencies and you probably won't use it anyway.

You will probably get some errors about the logger class. You can either remove the few logging lines or like i did write a tiny wrapper which communicates with android.util.Log. I did that and changed the includes.

If you finished importing the code take a look at jUnrars testutils.
I used this and it worked out of the box:

https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar/blob/master/testutil/src/main/java/com/github/junrar/testutil/ExtractArchive.java

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

RAR isn't very commonly used (except in certain niches), so you won't find support for it built into the Android libraries. Probably the easiest thing to do is to get a Java library that handles RAR files, as covered in this question:

[RAR archives with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561107/rar-archives-with-java)