# How to Programmatically Open RAR File with Password using Java (or other language)

Tags: java, python, passwords, rar, unrar

How do you open a RAR file and enter the password programmatically? I'd like to use Java or Python if possible, but any programming language should be fine.

Comment: For Java, you should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561107/rar-archives-with-java

Answer (score 1):

For Python you'd need this: ["RAR archive reader for Python"](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/2.5)