# How to extract a password protected .rar file in java?

Tags: java, rar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RAR archives with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561107/rar-archives-with-java)

In a java project I am working on I need to extract a .rar file that is password protected. I do know the password. Does anybody know of a free API that does this?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561107/rar-archives-with-java

Answer (score -1):

You can downlaod use [WinZipAES](http://code.google.com/p/winzipaes/downloads/detail?name=winzipaes_src_20120819.zip).

It has classes such as `de.idyl.winzipaes.AesZipFileEncrypter` and `de.idyl.winzipaes.AesZipFileDecrypter`, which might be useful for you.

This small utility program uses `java.util.zip` package internally.

Comment: Doesn't that only deal with .zip files? This isn't what I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I thought you want to create a file. Please looks at this- [Password Protected Zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587561/password-protected-zip-file-in-java). Hope that helps.